# GLCM function for RasterStack using FOR loop in R

Tags: raster, r, for-loop, texture

I would like to calculate glcm function in R for all (52) bands in my RasterStack. Using this code:

```
LS<-stack(img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10,img11,img12,img13)

names(LS) <-  paste0("B", c(1:52))

band<-brick()

for (i in 1:52){    
     band[i]<-glcm(LS$B1,window = c(3, 3),na_opt = 'center')
    }
```

I get 1 layer RasterBrick with NA values and an error message:
1: In x@data@values[i] <- value :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Do you know how to get the result for all the bands in my RasterStack?

Comment: Does the loop successfully run through all 52 iterations? Or does it exit on a certain value of `i`?

Comment: It goes through all the iterations but I got this message for 52 times: 1: In x@data@values[i] <- value : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Ok, have you tried running `glcm` on `img1` before stacking it with anything else? If so, do you get the same error message?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that and it worked for one selected band. It works for one band using RasterStack as well with this code: `glcm(LS$B1,window = c(3, 3),na_opt = 'center')`

Comment: Does it make a difference if `band` is a `stack` instead of a `brick`?

Comment: Using `stack` instead of `brick` I get this error: `Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glcm` function outputs a `stack`, with each band containing values for each of the statistics calculated. By default, all available statistics are computed.

You won't be able to put this `stack` into a single band within the `brick` as you are trying with `band[i]<-`. This is probably what is giving you the error message.

One solution would be to output each `stack` to a `list` and then look at stacking them together once the loop has completed.

Something like this should work:

```
out <- list()

for(i in 1:dim(LS)[3]) {

  out[i] <- glcm::glcm(LS[[i]], window = c(3, 3), na_opt = 'center')

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use `list` instead of `brick` usign this code                           
`LS<-stack(img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10,img11,img12,img13)

names(LS) <-  paste0("B", c(1:52))

band<-list()

for (i in 1:52){    
     band[i]<-glcm(LS$B1,window = c(3, 3),na_opt = 'center')
    }` and it went through 52 iterations but they were all calculated for the band B1. And I also get this warning `implicit list embedding of S4 objects is deprecated`

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with the deprecated warning, but I have added suggested code to my answer to ensure the list contains the unique stacks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The code you suggested works. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @roubalma Happy to help. Please mark the answer with the green tick if you feel it has helped with your issue.